# How to replace specific letters in multiple times in strings in python,

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

#some times it will change" JR" as " II" that time this replace function not work

Comment: a="sai. jr"   #input

Comment: b=a.replace(" jr") # sai

Comment: Your question is unclear can you just elaborate.

Comment: #some times it will change" JR" as " II" that time this replace function not work. I want to use the same function, to replace multiple letters in same function. I am new to python please help me.

Comment: No. Help us to help you. Provide a [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly. We are not some free help service that can guess at what you're trying to do. As it stands, the question is nonsensical

Comment: You need to explain what "it" is

Comment: Please fully explain your question, its not explanatory enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for that. But if it's just these two cases(Jr and II) just use replace twice `string.replace("JR","").replace("II","")`

Comment: the string value will be change some times, I want to use replace the same function to replace "S"  as  "A",

Comment: Thank you so much, I need to replace those cases only, It worked for me